# whois returns correct changed date but wrong nameservers

Tags: database, nameserver, a-record, whois

I was just told by 1&1 customer support that "the date in the whois could show correctly while the nameservers information being the old one"

I though the whole document was stamped at once, not "built" from different data sources.

Am I being lied to? or how is that possible?

The site is not visible yet, the whois shows correct date the change was made, and the nameservers are still wrong in that report/record/document and of course in the world's dns servers.

Comment: What? Please try to imagine that you're someone unfamiliar with your situation, and read your question again.  Then add enough details and relevant information to make it... not so confusing to such a person, for example, all of us on this site.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. So you changed your nameserver information at 1&1 and you are still seeing the old information?

Answer (score 3):

1. The WHOIS information has no direct relation to your name servers. DNS resolvers don't query the WHOIS servers to find your name servers, they query the gTLD servers responsible for the gTLD that your domain resides in. That being said, you should make sure that the WHOIS information is correct.
2. No name servers other than your name servers have a copy of your zone or have any direct relation to your name servers. DNS doesn't propagate and my name servers don't know jack about your name servers until one of my DNS clients requests a resource in your domain, in fact, my name servers don't even know that your domain exists. My name servers (if they don't have the information cached) will query the gTLD server(s) for the gTLD in question asking for your name servers. The gTLD server(s) will then refer me to your name server(s), where my DNS server will send it's query for the resource in question. Once my DNS server has an answer from your name server it will then cache that answer for the period of the TTL on the resource record. Once the TTL expires it will be as if that resource record doesn't exist. The same is true for your NS records. Once the NS record for your domain expires in my DNS server cache my DNS server will have to query the gTLD server(s) again for your name servers. As you can see, "the world's" dns servers don't have wrong information about your name servers. Only DNS servers that have queried the gTLD server for your name servers will have the wrong information, and only for the duration of the TTL for the NS records, and only for as long as you leave it uncorrected. What you need to do is to verify that your domain Registrar has the correct name servers listed for your domain.